# Installing Linux on HP Pavilion 360, preventing loops that eat all resources

Tags: linux, software-installation, grub, live-usb

When installing a Linux OS (e.g. Mint) from a live cd (now more likely: from a live USB stick, or using Ventoy), editing /etc/default/grub does not solve the problem. You can add or edit a line like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
```

there, and running update-grub (which internally uses grub-mkconfig) will transfer that to /boot/grub/grub.cfg .

But that becomes effective only after a reboot, and when you reboot a Linux live session (i.e. without having installed anything to hard disk yet), the live stick will restore ITS grub settings again, so you have the interrupt looping problem yet again.

The solution (I thought of it by accident, yesterday, I wish the idea had come up earlier!):
In the grub menu that the booted ISO, or Ventoy (or wherever it comes from) presents to you, press the letter e! That's e for edit. Then you can add pci=noaer there, just before the live session starts! And the looping problem will be gone!

This allowed me to finally install Linux Mint 21.1 Vera on my HP Pavilion 360 laptop.

Before, there was a process constantly doing interrupt 123, AND two processes that logged that 'error' (a harmless error, automatically fixed) to two different log files! In the live environment, there is a squashfs file system, that actually resides in RAM, and which is limited in size. So after a minute or so, on a very slow computer because the processors were kept busy all the time, it ran out of 'disk' space, and the computer got stuck and became completely unresponsive and unusable. Impossible to do the install I wanted to do.

After the "e for edit" trick, the problem was gone, I could install the OS to harddisk, and THEN I still had to edit /etc/default/grub, run update-grub, and reboot, to make the solution permanent. I felt so relieved!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to this community! This is a *question and answer* site, and your post in the *question* field seems to be more of a blog post, and not a question! Could you take the answer part from your post and move it into the *answer* field below? That would make your post fit the format of this site. Self-answered questions **are highly welcome**, but they do need to fit the clearly separated question post –> answer post formalism.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.